# Google AutoComplete Search bar issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When we use google autocomplete search bar for a particular country then all address not shown of that country.

**Example address:**

> Park Hyatt Sydney, Hickson Road, The Rocks NSW, Australia.

**I am using following code:**

```
var countryRestrict = {'country': 'au'};    
function initAutocomplete() { 
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                     (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                     {types: ['geocode'],componentRestrictions: countryRestrict});
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}
```

Comment: *"then all address not shown"* To avoid misunderstandings: Do you mean **no** addresses are shown (*all not*), or do you mean **some** are shown, and some are not? (*not all*)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `country` restriction that made you get no results. It's the `types: ['geocode']`. The reason behind this is because the place type of **Park Hyatt Sydney, Hickson Road, The Rocks NSW, Australia.** is an `establishment` and not `geocode`.

If you would use this:

```
var options = {
    types: ['establishment'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
};
```

then you will be able to see the result for that place.

Remember: If you add a type restriction to your autocomplete, then it will only show results with that certain type. In your case, you used `geocode` and searched for a type `establishment`. The **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_restrict)** says this:

> You may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a certain type by passing a types parameter.

It also says there:

> `geocode` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results, rather than business results. Generally, you use this request to disambiguate results where the location specified may be indeterminate.

Hope this cleared up your confusion!